# Converting values to special character in summary

Tags: r

I have created a summary table like below

```
   Name Sales
    AS  71.5%
    DY  88.4%
    VH  44.6%
    MY  86.9%
    HU  42.3%
    TT  67.2%
    BG  0.0%
    SA  85.3%
```

now I want to replace the occurrence of 0.0 to "-"

I have tried

```
tab[,2] <- paste0(tab[,2],"%")
tab[,2] <- replace(tab[,2],tab[,2]<0,"-")
```

but its converting all values like 8.0 and 7.0 to "-"
do we have any other sollution

the output should be like

```
Name Sales

AS  71.5%

DY  88.4%

BG  -
```

so the whole function is like this, have three columns of os sales for each person

Comment: Please show your data using `dput()`. I think it's essential that we are using exactly the same data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
#Data

df <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(1L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 
6L), .Label = c("AS", "BG", "DY", "HU", "MY", "SA", "TT", "VH"
), class = "factor"), Sales = c(71.5, 88.4, 44.6, 86.9, 42.3, 
67.2, 0, 85.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
#Code
index <- which(df$Sales==0)
df$Sales[index] <- '-'

  Name Sales
1   AS  71.5
2   DY  88.4
3   VH  44.6
4   MY  86.9
5   HU  42.3
6   TT  67.2
7   BG     -
8   SA  85.3
```

**Update with new data**

New data has been provided:

```
df2 <- structure(list(Name = c("AS", "DY", "VH", "MY", "HU", "TT", "BG", 
"SA"), Sales = c("71.5%", "88.4%", "44.6%", "86.9%", "42.3%", 
"67.2%", "0.0%", "85.3%")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
df2$Sales2 <- gsub("0.0%","-",df2$Sales,fixed=T)



Name Sales Sales2
1   AS 71.5%  71.5%
2   DY 88.4%  88.4%
3   VH 44.6%  44.6%
4   MY 86.9%  86.9%
5   HU 42.3%  42.3%
6   TT 67.2%  67.2%
7   BG  0.0%      -
8   SA 85.3%  85.3%
```

**Update with variable**

Using first data `df`:

```
df$tab <- paste0(df$Sales,'%')
df$tab <- ifelse(nchar(df$tab)==2,gsub("0%","-",df$tab,fixed=T),df$tab)

  Name Sales   tab
1   AS  71.5 71.5%
2   DY  88.4 88.4%
3   VH  44.6 44.6%
4   MY  86.9 86.9%
5   HU  42.3 42.3%
6   TT  67.2 67.2%
7   BG   0.0     -
8   SA  85.3 85.3%
```

Comment: As `Sales` is numeric you can set `0` for replacement.

Comment: this is working but I have range of values in decimal point, so like suppose if values is 10.0 so its converting "1-", because I also have to show decimal point

Comment: @rjunkie2 Updated! Sorry for the confusion! Let me know if it works!

Comment: do we have any solution like  gsub() or sub()

Comment: Based on your data you could try: `index <- which(df$Sales=='0.0%')` or `gsub('0.0%','-',df$Sales)` @rjunkie2 Let me know if this helps!

Comment: its working but if the value is  10.0% or 60.0%  so its get converting to "1-" or "6-"

Comment: @rjunkie2 Check this `gsub("0.0%","-","89.0%",fixed=T)` and this `gsub("0.0%","-","0.0%",fixed=T)`, is that what you look for?

Comment: tab[,2] <- paste0(tab[,2],"%")
  tab[,2] <- gsub("0.0%","-","0.0%",fixed=T)

all values converting to  "-" with this,  may I am using wrong please help

Comment: @rjunkie2 It looks like, `tab` is the first version of data right?

Comment: @rjunkie2 You must use `tab[,2] <- gsub("0%","-",tab[,2],fixed=T)`

Comment: its working but if the value is 10.0% or 60.0% so its get converting to "1-" or "6-"
I have to apply this for many tables...

Comment: Add a condition I will help you updating the post @rjunkie2

Comment: @rjunkie2 I have updated the solution in the final side, please check and let me know if this worked!

Comment: Thanks , but still its not working
 `tab[,2] <- paste0(tab[,2],"%")
  tab[,2] <- ifelse(nchar(tab[,2])==2,gsub("0.0%","-",tab[,2],fixed=T),tab[,2])`
am I doing right way...??

Comment: ` tab[,2] <- paste0(tab[,2],"%")
  tab[,2] <- ifelse(nchar(tab[,2])==2,gsub("0%","-",tab[,2],fixed=T),tab[,2])`

also tried this
nchar(tab[,2]) giving result  5  5  5

Comment: @rjunkie2 I have added the code, `nchar()` check the length of your values as `0%` will have 2, then it will be replaced. Let me know if worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tab$Sales <- replace(tab$Sales, which(tab$Sales == 0), "-")
```

I'd also recommend looking into dplyr's `mutate`.

Comment: Apologies :( In that case, could you edit your post to contain a reproducible example? If not, perhaps try changing `which(tab$Sales == 0)` to `which(tab$Sales == "0.0%")` if you've reformatted sales already.